# How to change the properties from one ViewController's function?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have two Controller which names are `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController`

the `FirstViewController` is the MainPage and I add a `UITextView` here.

```
var secondViewController: SecondViewController!

let textView: UITextView = {
    let textView = UITextView()
    //textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    textView.isEditable = true
    textView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
    textView.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
    return textView
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    secondViewController = SecondViewController()

    setUpLayout() //do something like add the textView to the view
    addKeyboardObserver() //a function which observe the keyboard
}
```

then I add a button to show secondView as a keyboard

```
@objc func showSecondView() {
    textView.resignFirstResponder()
    textView.inputView = secondViewController.view
    textView.becomeFirstResoonder()
}
```

then I define a function to close the secondView

```
func closeSecondView() {
    textView.resignFirstResponder()
    textView.inputView = nil
}
```

in my `SecondViewController`

```
var firstViewController: FirstViewController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    firstViewController = FirstViewController()

    self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 300)
    self.view.backgroundColor = .cyan
}
```

then I add a button to close the firstViewController's custom keyboard

```
@objc func closeFontView() {
    print(123)
    firstViewController.closeSecondView()
}
```

the result is, "123" is printed, then I add a breakpoint at `closeFontView()`, it is called. but the change of UI isn't show up.(the keyboard is not be closed) Why? how can I fix that?

Comment: Why `firstViewController = FirstViewController()`? you already have that `viewController` as you're doing this inside `viewDidLoad`. So you need not to create a new one

Comment: @KamaldeepsinghBhatia the second one is needed. Otherwise where is it created?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Oh, sorry I thought it is done inside `SecondViewController`

Comment: This is a little OT, but watch out for memory leaks. Two view controllers holding strong references to each other creates a strong reference cycle. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ID52

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `secondViewController`, store the instance of the `firstViewController`.

```
var secondViewController: SecondViewController!

let textView: UITextView = {
    let textView = UITextView()
    //textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    textView.isEditable = true
    textView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
    textView.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
    return textView
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    secondViewController = SecondViewController()
    secondViewController.firstViewController = self  // <- add this line

    setUpLayout() //do something like add the textView to the view
    addKeyboardObserver() //a function which observe the keyboard
}
```

Now remove the initialization of `FirstViewController` in `SecondViewController` because you need the **same instance** and not another one.

```
var firstViewController: FirstViewController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //firstViewController = FirstViewController() <-- remove this line

    self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 300)
    self.view.backgroundColor = .cyan
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here [Remove this line]

```
firstViewController = FirstViewController() // new instance not the real presented first
```

connect it like this when you show the second , This inside ( `firstViewController` )

```
let second = ///
second.first = self
// present second
```

Comment: what is the second in your code? I just can't find the "first" property

Comment: second  is an instance of the secondVC  , How do you show it segue/push.present

Comment: I just know what you mean, I just create an another instance of the firstView, however, thx so much